# POST a file to my Tp-link router using python requests

Tags: python, post, router

I'm trying to write a Python script that will upgrade my router's (TP-LINK) firmware.

In order to do that, I upgraded my firmware from the Admin web interface and sniffed it with Wireshark. Then I built the exact POST request with Python, but for some reason it's not working (I get FIN from the router).

This is my code:

```
import httplib, mimetypes

fields = {"Upgrade":"Upgrade"}
files = {"Filename":"k.bin"}
uri = "/incoming/Firmware.htm"
host="Router's IP"

def post_multipart(host, uri, fields, files):
    content_type, body = encode_multipart_formdata(fields, files)
    h = httplib.HTTPConnection(host)
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Xll; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008070208 Firefox/3.0.1',
        'Content-Type': content_type,
        'Authorization': 'Basic xxxxxxxxxxx=',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
        'Connection':'keep-alive',
        'Referer':'http://Routers IP/userRpm/SoftwareUpgradeRpm.htm',
        'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.5'
        }
    h.request('POST', uri, body, headers)
    res = h.getresponse()
    return res.status, res.reason, res.read() 

def encode_multipart_formdata(fields, files):
    """
    fields is a sequence of (name, value) elements for regular form fields.
    files is a sequence of (name, filename, value) elements for data to be uploaded as     files
    Return (content_type, body) ready for httplib.HTTP instance
    """
    BOUNDARY = '-----------------------------19933564951268966553507360333'
    CRLF = '\r\n'
    L = []
    print "Uploading..."
    for key, filename in files.items():
        L.append('--' + BOUNDARY)
        L.append('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="%s"; filename="%s"' % (key, filename))
        L.append('Content-Type: %s' % get_content_type(filename))
        L.append('')
        L.append(open("k.bin","rb").read())
    for key, value in fields.items():
        L.append('--' + BOUNDARY)
        L.append('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="%s"' % key)
        L.append('')
        L.append(value)
    L.append('--' + BOUNDARY + '--')
    L.append('')
    body = CRLF.join(L)
    content_type = 'multipart/form-data; boundary=%s' % BOUNDARY
    return content_type, body

def get_content_type(filename):
    return mimetypes.guess_type(filename)[0] or 'application/octet-stream'

post_multipart(host, uri, fields, files)
```

Help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Normally you have to reboot the router to see the changes of the upgrade. The code you posted is not rebooting the router. Did you reboot the router manually and checked if it is not upgraded?

Comment: Thank you for your help. The router should reboot itself after the upgrade. rebooting manually didn't help.

Comment: It doesn't really matters if you reboot the router manually or automatically, if the firmware if uploaded successfully it will update router's firmware. Regarding the reboot issue you can simply create one more post request for the reboot, as you have done for uploading the firmware, by sniffing the post request using wireshark when you reboot the router manually. I can't test your code as I don't have a router like yours.

Comment: Im connected to the router with a serial port, so i can see that the firmware is not upgraded...

Comment: any luck @user3560554